# Java 2 dimensional array of Strings error

Tags: java

```
public class RobotZoneClass implements RobotZone {
    String[][] map;

    public RobotZoneClass(int rows, int columns){
        map= new String[rows][columns];
    }

    public void readMap(String map,int row) {
        for(int i=0;i<map.length()-1;i++){
            map[row][i]=map.charAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error: `The type of expression must be an array type but it resolved to String.`
 Why is this happening?

Comment: I tried it and got no error. Can you show more of the code?

Comment: Include a full example of your code. Your snippet does not include enough context.

Comment: @stvcisco Just added the code I use

Comment: @b4hand Just added the code I use

Comment: May I ask what are attempting to do? @JoãoSimões

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the global `map` variable:

> In computer programming, variable shadowing occurs when a variable declared within a certain scope (decision block, method, or inner class) has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope.

Rename the parameter to `readMap`:

```
public void readMap(String otherMap,int row) {
    for(int i=0;i<map.length()-1;i++){
        map[row][i]=otherMap.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

Also, it seems like you're using a two-dimensional array of strings (which is like a three-dimensional array of characters) as a map when all you want is a two-dimensional **character** array, which is just like an array of strings.

Try this:

```
public class RobotZoneClass implements RobotZone {
    String[] map;

    public RobotZoneClass(int rows){
        map = new String[rows];
    }


    public void readMap(String newRow, int row) {
        // replaces row in map
        map[row]=newRow;
    }

    // rest of implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your local variable `String map` (first parameter for the `readMap` method) is hiding your class variable `map` so the compiler is complaining that you are accessing a `String` as an array. If you are passing a `String` in the first parameter it must have a different variable name. Your method can be fixed like this:

```
public void readMap(String value, int row) {
    for(int i=0; i<value.length()-1; i++) {
        map[row][i] = value.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

You may also have a bug with your `for` loop end condition. I suspect you really meant `i<value.length();` unless you really need to ignore the last character.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
public class Maps{
    static String[][] map;
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    RobotZoneClass(2, 2);

    }
    public static void RobotZoneClass(int rows, int columns){
        map= new String[rows][columns];
        map[1][1]="E";
        System.out.println(map[1][1]);
    }
}
```